# Extract strings from filename and create new columns using mutate

Tags: r, stringr, dplyr

I have a data.frame with two columns. In the second column are filenames.

```
df  <- data.frame(paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
             filename = "./data/RevCon_2015_C1_Austria_05_06.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How can I extract certain strings (using `stringr`) from this second column and add them (using `dplyr::mutate`) as additional variables (conference, year, country, etc.) so that I get the following result:

```
df2  <- data.frame(paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
              filename = "./data/RevCon_2015_C1_Austria_05_06.txt", conference = "RevCon", year = "2015", country= "Austria", date = "06.05.2015", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do all entries in column `filename` have the same pattern? I.e.  `./data/{conference}_{year}_{ignored}_{country}_{month}_{day}.txt`?

Comment: most of them, yes. there are some exceptions, but I think I can filter them and extract these informations in a second run and then join both datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following using `tidyr::separate`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(tmp = gsub("(\\./data/|\\.txt)", "", filename)) %>%
    separate(
        tmp,
        into = c("conference", "year", "ignored", "country", "month", "day")) %>%
    mutate(date = paste(day, month, year, sep = "/")) %>%
    select(-ignored, -month, -day)
#          paragraph                                filename conference year
#1 Lorem ipsum [...] ./data/RevCon_2015_C1_Austria_05_06.txt     RevCon 2015
#  country        date
#1 Austria  06/05/2015
```

Note this assumes that `filename`s adhere to the following pattern: `./data/{conference}_{year}_{ignored}_{country}_{month}_{day}.txt`

---

### Sample data

```
df  <- data.frame(
    paragraph = "Lorem ipsum [...]",
    filename = "./data/RevCon_2015_C1_Austria_05_06.txt",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different approaches using `separate` and `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(filename2 = gsub("^(\\w+)_(\\d+)_.+?_(\\w+)_(\\d{2})_(\\d{2}).+$", 
                          "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\5.\\4.\\2", basename(filename))) %>%
  separate(filename2, c("conference", "year", "country", "date"), sep = "_")
```

or with `extract`:

```
df %>%
  extract(filename, c("conference", "year", "country", "day", "month"),
          "^.+/(\\w+)_(\\d+)_.+?_(\\w+)_(\\d{2})_(\\d{2}).+$",
          remove = FALSE) %>%
  unite(date, month, day, year, sep = ".", remove = FALSE) %>%
  select(paragraph, filename, conference, year, country, date)
```

**Result:**

```
                                                                   paragraph
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                                 filename conference year country       date
1 ./data/RevCon_2015_C1_Austria_05_06.txt     RevCon 2015 Austria 06.05.2015
```

**Notes:**

1. The first approach uses `gsub` to match each "column" we want using capture groups, and re-order as desired. Notice that `_` is added in to distinguish between columns

   - I used the `basename` function to extract everything after the last `/`
   - `separate` is then used to split the elements into actual columns with `_` being the separator
2. The second approach uses the same regex but instead of rearranging, `extract` treats each capture group as a separate column

   - `unite` binds `month`, `day` and `year` together without removing the original columns
   - Finally `select` removes `day` and `month` and rearranges the column order